# Linear field in $\mathbb{R^4}$ such that $\gamma\subset \omega(\gamma)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

I was wondering if there is a example of a Linear field $F:\mathbb{R^4}\to\mathbb{R^4}$(i.e. F(x)=Ax, where A is a 4x4 matrix) such that $F$ admit a non-singular and non-periodic orbit $\gamma$, with the propriety that $\gamma\subset \omega(\gamma)$.

Comment: Which orbit are you looking at? The flow of the associated ODE? Or the iterated discrete flow? And what is $\omega (\gamma)$?

Comment: the flow associated with the ODE X'=F(X). $ \omega(\gamma)$ denotes the  Omega-limit set of $\gamma$

Comment: This is not possible. Wlog you can assume that $A$ is in real Jordan normal form. Furthermore you can also assume that you start in one of the invariant subspaces associated to the Jordan blocks (if you had such an orbit, then the projection of this orbit to the invariant subspaces had the same property) If your orbit is not periodic, you don't have simple nonreal eigenvalues and hence the norm either explodes or goes to zero when you apply the flow (this you see, when explicitely computing the exponential of the matrix). Hence, there is no such orbit.

Comment: The argument I gave above is wrong, it would only work if we would assume that there are no periodic orbits at all. Otherwise one can use the example I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it is possible. The idea is to take two rotations with frequencies which are incommensurable. Then the orbit is not periodic, but in the forward limit you get everything on the torus we are walking on (the quasiperiodic motion lies dense on the torus).

Take $f_1 , f_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then consider

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & f_1 &0 & 0 \\
-f_1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0& 0& 0 & f_2 \\
0 & 0 & -f_2 &0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then the flow of the associated ODE is given by for $x= (x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^4$

$$ e^{tA} x = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(t f_1) & - \sin(t f_1) & 0 &0 \\
\sin(t f_1) & \cos(t f_1) & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0& \cos(t f_2) & - \sin(t f_1) \\
0 &0 & \sin(t f_2) & \cos(t f_2)
\end{pmatrix} x $$

Thus, we get that the orbit $\gamma$ of $x$ is contained in a torus depending on $x$. More precisely

$$\gamma \subseteq \{ (y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \ : \ \vert y_1 \vert = \vert x_1 \vert, \ \vert y_2 \vert = \vert x_2 \vert \} $$

Next we prove

$$\omega(\gamma) = \{ (y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \ : \ \vert y_1 \vert = \vert x_1 \vert, \ \vert y_2 \vert = \vert x_2 \vert \}.$$

Pick $(y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\vert y_1 \vert = \vert x_1 \vert, \ \vert y_2 \vert = \vert x_2 \vert.$ There exists $t_0$ such that

$$ y_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(t_0 f_1) & - \sin(t_0 f_1) \\
\sin(t_0 f_1) & \cos(t_0 f_1)
\end{pmatrix} x_1. $$

Now we set $T=2\pi/f_1$, then we get for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$$ e^{(t+nT)A}x = \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos((t_0+nT) f_2) & - \sin((t_0+nT) f_2) \\
\sin((t_0+nT) f_2) & \cos((t_0+nT) f_2)
\end{pmatrix} x_2
\end{pmatrix}.$$

As $f_1, f_2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$, we have that

$$ \left(\begin{pmatrix}
\cos((t_0+nT) f_2) & - \sin((t_0+nT) f_2) \\
\sin((t_0+nT) f_2) & \cos((t_0+nT) f_2)
\end{pmatrix}x_2 \right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$

lies dense in $\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ \vert z \vert = \vert x_2 \vert \}$ and hence, find a sequence $(n_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} e^{(t_0+n_kT)A}x =y.$$

I.e. $y\in \omega(\gamma)$. As our flow preserves the norm, we get that

$$ \omega(\gamma) = \{ (y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \ : \ \vert y_1 \vert = \vert x_1 \vert, \ \vert y_2 \vert = \vert x_2 \vert \} $$

and thus $\gamma \subseteq \omega(\gamma)$. Note that the orbit is not periodic if $\vert x_1 \vert \neq 0$ and $\vert x_2 \vert \neq 0$, as the frequencies $f_1,f_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: what a great example! thanks a lot @severin-schraven

Comment: @PiresDankan You are welcome. Sorry for the confusion in the comments. By the way, one could also prove that in this case we have $ \gamma \subsetneq \omega(\gamma) $.